# What causes the "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to add a new Back Order to the Back Order table in my MYSQL database. The problem I'm getting is that when I try to select the Supplier_ID to add it to the Back Order Table, the program gives me an error that says "Subquery returns more than 1 value".

Supplier Table (Unsure how to properly structure it)

> | Supplier_ID |     SupName     |
>
> |           1| EWS             |
>
> |           6 | Franklin Bakery |

Back Order Table

> | BackOr_ID | Supplier_ID | BackOr_Org_Date | Sup_Name |

The MYSQL query I'm currently using is:

```html
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_BackOrder`(
in supname varchar(50),
in dat date
)
BEGIN
insert into Back_Order
(
Supplier_ID,
BackOr_Org_Date,
Sup_Name
)
values
(
(select Supplier_ID from Supplier Where SupName = supname),
dat,
supname
);

END
```

The C# Code that uses the query is:

```html
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("sp_BackOrder", new MySqlConnection(*Connection String*));
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("supname", Supp_Name)); //Supp_Name is the Supplier Name (a string variable)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("dat", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())); //dat is the date the Order is placed
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Connection.Close();
```

The only error I get is that the Subquery (Which I assume is the Select Query) returns more than 1 value. I've tried looking around and even looked on Stackoverflow but couldn't find any solution to the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your values block makes no sense

Comment: Is the `SupName` field unique? Should it be?

Comment: The sub query `select Supplier_ID from Supplier Where SupName = supname` returns more than 1 value because you have at least 2 suppliers in your database with the same name. When using such sub queries search by unique columns.

Comment: I'm sorry for the strange formatting of the Table. The Suppliers in the table are (ID: 1)EWS and (ID: 6)Frankies Bakery. There isn't more than one supplier with the same name. 

SupName is the name of the Column that shows the Supplier Names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter name `supname`  of procedure and column name `SupName` are same. Change parameter name to something other than column name.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_BackOrder`(
in selectedSupname varchar(50),
in dat date
)
BEGIN
insert into Back_Order
(
Supplier_ID,
BackOr_Org_Date,
Sup_Name
)
values
(
(select Supplier_ID from Supplier Where SupName = selectedSupname),
dat,
selectedSupname
);

END
```

Comment: When I add LIMIT 1 to the query, it only returns the first Supplier no matter what Supplier name is set to the supname variable.

Comment: How many insertions in the table you want for each suppplier?

Comment: The query should only add the Supplier_ID of the Supplier we place the Order with. So each Order we place should add a new line with whichever Supplier that was selected in the combobox. So when I choose "EWS" it should add the Supplier_ID 1 and if I choose "Frankies Bakery" it should add the Supplier_ID 6. By adding LIMIT 1 it just always adds the Supplier_ID 1 regardless of the Supplier that was selected. If that makes sense.

Comment: So you need only one row row for each of your orders? For each of your orders how many times this procedure is called?

Comment: Yes each line is just a summary of the Order Number and the Supplier and the Date the Order was placed. Each line would represent a different Order.

Comment: In C# the Procedure is only called once when a button is clicked.

Comment: Where SupName = supname in this clause both LHS and RHS are treated as column names. thats why multiple rows in result are returned. change parameter name of stored proc

Answer (score 1):

It would need to look like:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_BackOrder`
(   in p_supname varchar(50),
    in p_dat date
)
BEGIN
    insert into Back_Order(Supplier_ID, BackOr_Org_Date, Sup_Name)
    select Supplier_ID, p_dat, p_supname from Supplier Where SupName = p_supname;
END$$
delimiter ;
```

or

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_BackOrder`
(   in p_supname varchar(50),
    in p_dat date
)
BEGIN
    insert into Back_Order(Supplier_ID, BackOr_Org_Date, Sup_Name)
    select Supplier_ID, p_dat, p_supname from Supplier Where SupName = p_supname;
END
```

Same deal in both just depending on your `DELIMITER` needs.

Comment: The date is added through the C# parameters and the supname is used, because the Supplier Name is taken from a combobox. That means I can't select the dat and supname from the Supplier table.